# Boot looping from usb

Tags: windows-10, usb, motherboard, reboot, infinite-loop

I just build a new pc and everytime i try to boot from the usb to install windows 10 it reboots.
The motherboard im using is the ASRock x570 taichi with a ryzen 9 3900x cpu.
I have tried enabling csm, legacy only mode, secure boot, pretty much everything i can think of plz help, im going crazy.
My motherboard detects the usb drive and it boots but when it shows the windows logo it reboots after.
I have been searching everywere and dont seem to find a solucion.

Comment: Could be issue with the `Windows` it self.

Comment: Why Legacy and not UEFI? The default for Windows 10 is UEFI.

Comment: @K7AAY yes, i have also tries UEFI, just forgot to type it, and it didnt work

Comment: You should be using UEFI for BIOS. Also make sure you have a full Windows ISO and not the Repair ISO. It should not be any issue with Windows at all.

Comment: @John yes, i have installed windows directly from microsoft site  and i have used uefi it just didnt work. Like i said it goes to the windows logo and reboots

Comment: Update the BIOS for you machine and then also Video drivers. If the SSD or HDD is good (no hardware errors) and drivers are up to date, then Windows should load. I have done this on my own Desktop computer changing from HDD to SSD and it loaded fine.

Comment: @John i did update the BIOS, but what do you mean by video drivers? U mean the graphics card?

Comment: Probably the drivers would come at the Windows install. Are you sure the disk is free of errors?

Comment: @John pretty sure, i used the usb on my old computer to see if it work and it did, the same for the ssd. I switched from intel to amd so i unistalled everything in my ssd to do a clean install in my new pc, but it just reboots keeps rebooting with the usb.